# How to align icon with text underneath

Tags: html, css

The text under the icon starts from far back. I couldn't find a solution as I'm not even beginner on HTML or CSS. If you can help me how to align the text I'd appreciate it.

[image: 1]

Here is the HTML code:

```html
A great fit for startups and scaleups:
<ul>
    <li>Export data from your <strong><a href="https://bettermetrics.io/data-sources/">Marketing Data Sources</a></strong></li>
    <li>Export your Marketing data to Google Sheets</li>
    <li><strong>Daily refresh</strong> of data</li>
    <li>Unlimited data sources</li>
    <li>1 user</li>
    <li>1 account per data source</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't seem to reproduce the image you uploaded, can you update it to create the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul.inside {
  max-width: 200px; 
  list-style-position: outside;
  }
  
</style>

</head>
<body>
<ul class="inside">
   
    <li>Export data from your <strong><a href="https://bettermetrics.io/data-sources/">Marketing Data Sources</a></strong></li>
    <li>Export your Marketing data to Google Sheets</li>
    <li><strong>Daily refresh</strong> of data</li>
    <li>Unlimited data sources</li>
    <li>1 user</li>
    <li>1 account per data source</li>
</ul>
</body>
<html>
```

You can approach it this way.

```css
ul.inside {
  max-width: 200px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  }
```

```html
A great fit for startups and scaleups:
<ul class="inside">
   
    <li>Export data from your <strong><a href="https://bettermetrics.io/data-sources/">Marketing Data Sources</a></strong></li>
    <li>Export your Marketing data to Google Sheets</li>
    <li><strong>Daily refresh</strong> of data</li>
    <li>Unlimited data sources</li>
    <li>1 user</li>
    <li>1 account per data source</li>
</ul>

<br>
<br>
<h3>THIS IS ANOTHER WAY</h3>

<ul style="max-width: 200px; list-style-position: outside;">
   
    <li>Export data from your <strong><a href="https://bettermetrics.io/data-sources/">Marketing Data Sources</a></strong></li>
    <li>Export your Marketing data to Google Sheets</li>
    <li><strong>Daily refresh</strong> of data</li>
    <li>Unlimited data sources</li>
    <li>1 user</li>
    <li>1 account per data source</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Crystal thank you very much for your qucik reply. Only issue is I don't know where and how I implement the code you gave me. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: do you have a css file? if you dont have it. you can put <style>ul.inside {
  max-width: 200px;
  list-style-position: outside;
  } </style> just  above the closing </head> then put the class="inside" your ul

Comment: @Ata look at above options you have 2 options you can put your code inline, if you dont have a css file, or if you do just put css inside your file or I would suggest you learn basic html and css so you can kind a understand where things go just as a start. Once you learn it, it will not gonna be very hard for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Crystal. I've started my HTML course just 2 days ago and my manager asked me to change the paragraphs and this created a trainwreck for me :) . I use WP I'll try to implement the code. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @Ata I am pretty sure this will not fix your issue because (1) outside is already the default value for lists (2) judging from your screenshot you are not using list-style at all. Please don't accept answers until you are sure it works for you. Try first and come back to accept it

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm not a developer, I only have this task to be solved - if you can lead me how to solve this issue I'd appreciate it.